# how to convert array in javascript ["a", "b", "c", "d"] to [{"a", "c"}, {"b,"d"}]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i have array javascript`array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];` and `array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];`
and how to convert array1 to `[{"a", "c"}, {"b,"d"}];` and how to convert array2 to `[{"a", "c", "e"}, {"b", "d", "f"}];`

Comment: The expected output `[{"a", "c"}, {"b,"d"}];` and `[{"a", "c", "e"}, {"b", "d", "f"}]` is wrong.Object should have key and value

Comment: SO is more about Wh-questions rather than the How question.so show us **WHAT** you have tried.

Comment: ...That's not how objects work

Answer (score 1):

For loop which iterates index + 2 and appends value to x array

For loop which iterates index + 1 and appends value to y array

Then do whatever you need with those arrays :)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

a,c are the odd indices and b,d are the even indices. So,

- a and c can be separated with the increment of indices by 2.

  "initialize the 'i' value with '0' ".

  for (i = 0; i < array length; i=i+2) {
  // Your code here 
  }
- b and d can be separated with the increment of indices by 2 .

  "initialize the 'i' value with '1' ".

  for (i = 1; i < array length; i=i+2) {
  //Your code here
  }